# HTML and Accessibility mode differences in Blue Prism

Tags: html, process, automation, accessibility, spying

What are the differences in properties while using HTML or Accessibility mode in blue prism. When I use HTML mode it shows a big yellow rectangle but when accessibility mode is used it focus on the first input box. Are there any differences in properties that we get in these two modes. When one mode should be preferred to use over the other.

Answer (score 1):

HTML mode is mainly used for spying the elements in the web browser application. Big rectangles displayed are because of the back end code having particular elements in the source page.

Whereas accessibility mode can be used to detect the buttons which needs to be clicked in the web browser application.

I would advice to use HTML mode to detect the elements such as text box, drop down in browser based application and AA (accessibility) mode to detect the push buttons in web application.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with web-browser application you will use HTML mode, which will give you standard html atributes of elements that you are tring to use.

Accessibility mode, for me, is just a backup. When I'm having some problems with HTML mode. It'l give you much less atributes.